# Controlar evento TimeOut en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, webservice, excepciones

Estoy haciendo una consulta hacia un [webservice](http://ws.strikeiron.com/StrikeIron/EMV6Hygiene?WSDL) con VB.NET la cual me devuleve si se valido el mail exitosamente o si el email es invalido. 
Al mandarlo a llamar queda así:

```
Public Shared Function verificaremail(ByVal email As String) As String
    Try
        Dim siService As StrikeIron.EMV6Hygiene = New StrikeIron.EMV6Hygiene()
        Dim timeout As Integer = 30
        Dim OptionalSourceID = " "
        siService.VerifyEmail(email.Trim(), timeout, OptionalSourceID)
        return true
    Catch tex As TimeoutException
        return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        return False
    End Try
End Function
```

**Mi pregunta es:**¿Cómo puedo manejar la excepción que cuando hayan pasado los 30 segundos de la consulta?

Ya que actualmente me la esta tomando como "ex" y me esta retornando falso al hacer pruebas.

*Omiti los pasos para la autentificación ya que es irrelevante para el proceso, y no recibo error de esa parte.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas, puedes probar a capturar la excepción genérica y dentro mirar de qué tipo es en concreto con el método GetType():

```
Try
    Dim siService As StrikeIron.EMV6Hygiene = New StrikeIron.EMV6Hygiene()
    Dim timeout As Integer = 30
    Dim OptionalSourceID = " "
    siService.VerifyEmail(email.Trim(), timeout, OptionalSourceID)
    return true

Catch ex As Exception
    If ex.GetType() = Type.GetType("System.TimeoutException") Then
        return True
    Else
        return False
    End If
End Try
```

Un saludo.